# Probability Choosing 1, exactly 2 and 1 such that exactly 2

Tags: probability

You have 5 Red and 6 Black balls. You choose 4 randomly, without replacement.

A=First Ball is black
R=Exactly 2 are Red

Calculate: $P(R) , P(A \mid R) , P(A)$

Let B1,B2,B3,B4 = balls chosen

$P(A)=\frac{6}{11}$ Because when you pick 4 random balls, the very first one has the $P(A)=\frac{6}{11}$

$$P(R)=\frac{\binom42\frac{5}{11}^2 \binom42\frac{6}{11}^2}{\binom{11}4}$$

$P(A \mid R)=\frac{P(AR)}{P(R)}=\frac{P(R\mid A)P(A)}{P(R)}$,where $P(R\mid A)=\binom31\frac{6}{11}\binom32\frac{5}{11}^2$

That's what I have but I don't know if it's right.

Comment: I think you have a typo somewhere. A: first ball is black, should have 6/11 I think.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed: $$P(A)=\frac6{11}$$

---

$$P(R)=\frac{\binom52\binom62}{\binom{11}4}$$

There are $\binom{11}4$ possibilities when it comes to choosing $4$ balls out of $11$ and doing it under the condition that $2$ are red and $2$ are black there are $\binom52\times \binom62$ possibilities.

---

If $4$ balls are drawn under condition that $2$ of them are black and $2$ are red then each ball (also the first) has a probability $\frac24=\frac12$ to be black:$$P(A\mid R)=\frac12$$

Comment: How is the probability of it being black 1/2? If choosing a black ball out of 11 is 6/11?

Comment: You are asked for the probability of the first ball to be black *under condition that $2$ of the first $4$ balls drawn are black*. So you are actually choosing a ball out of $4$ and $2$ of them are black.